# AGM polygons binding does not update model

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, agm

```
 <div *ngFor="let p of polys">
      <agm-polygon #cmp [paths]="$any(p.getPath()).i" [fillColor]="'blue'" [draggable]="true" [editable]="true"
          [polyDraggable]="true" (polyPathsChange)="polytest($event,p)">
      </agm-polygon>
 </div>
```

when editing the polygon in the map my polygon path isn't updated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a process of AGM itself, which is when a AGM component load it will destroy all init processes and start with new inintitlization, AGM deson't have any 're-init' function yet. So I've find a solution to re-init AGM components.

Just put `<agm-map *ngIf="resetMap" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" #AgmMap>` before applying a function requirements.